# Powershell How to get lastwritetime file and log it

Tags: powershell

I have tried with powershell to check if files in a directory with subfolders do not have a changeover time of 10 hours (LastWriteTime).

If this is the case I would like to log its name and directory in a log.txt file and have an email alert.

So I did that, but it does not really work well ...  below any help is appreciated!

```
$directories ='C:\folders'
$Logfile = "C:\log.txt"
function logit($msg){
$msg='[{0}]{1}' -f [datetime]::Now, $msg
$msg|Out-File $logfile -append
}
if([datetime]::Now - (Get-Item $directories).LastWriteTime -gt  
[timespan]'0:10:0:0'){

Send-MailMessage -to "name <name@domain.com>" -from "name  
<name@domain.com>" -subject "object" -smtpserver "smtp.domain.com" ..
Out-File $Logfile
Write-Host 

}
```

Thank you

I try this, i get the good result. i'ts possible to modify "comparedate" in hours ?

```
$compareDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
@(Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp\*.* -Filter '*.*' -Recurse | Where-Object {    
$_.LastWriteTime -gt $compareDate})
```

Comment: What error do you get? Which part doesn't work? Can you be more specific?

Comment: Thank you to answering me. I don't have any error. I received the mail. But i don't any information about the file name and his location.

Comment: The edit is a different question, not an update to the same problem...  Are you looking for `(Get-Date).AddHours(-1)`?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$compareDate = (Get-Date).AddHours(-10)
Get-ChildItem "C:\temp\" -Recurse -file | Where LastWriteTime -gt $compareDate
```